# Smooth rotation in Processing

Tags: processing

I was looking at the Processing reference in my classroom and put together a couple of examples in an animation. My professor is not teaching this material in the classroom and told me I might find better luck getting help from the community on Stack Overflow. My problem follows.

When `ry` reaches 70 the rotation stops. I put a comment in my code at where the problem might be.

I am trying to make a continuous and smooth animation.

```java
int x = 200;
int y = 350;
int cubeWidth = 300;
int cubeHeight = 2;
float rY = 0.1; 
float rX = 0.1;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P3D);
}

void draw() { 

  background(3);
  lights();

  fill(247, 7, 12);

  rY = constrain(rY, 0, 70);
  rX = constrain(rX, 0, 70); 
  pushMatrix();
  translate(441, height/cubeHeight, 0);
  rY = rY + .005;
  println(rY);
  rotateY(rY);  // <--- here, when rY hits 70, it stops
  rX += rX;
  rotateX(rX);
  noStroke();
  box(69); 
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
  translate(470, height*0.49, -221);
   rY = rY + .005;
  println(rY);
  rotateY(rY); 
  rX += rX;
  rotateX(rX);
  noFill();
  stroke(238);
  sphere(282);
  popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you're telling it to do in this line of code:

```javascript
rY = constrain(rY, 0, 70);
```

The `constrain()` function limits a value to a min and a max, in this case `0` and `70`.

If you take that line out, your sketch keeps rotating. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/constrain_.html).

Note that you're doing weird things with the `rX` variable. You seem to be doubling it each time for some reason. This quickly gets too large if you don't constrain it. But since you only add `.005` to `rY`, you don't have to constrain it.

Answer (score 0):

as Kevin Workman said, `rY = constrain(rY, 0, 70);` was the problem. You just gave the rotation an end point. I changed the code a bit, because there were some logical mistakes so it kept adding values till infinity.

`rX += rX;` adds acceleration so after a while you get a big velocity of the object, for example ( 0.1 + 0.1 = 0.2; next frame 0.2 + 0.2 = 0.4 ... and so on ). If you could imagine that there are 100 frames per second, it gets really fast in no time. so you need only to add velocity, not the acceleration `rX +=  1` which each frame will update the rotation by one this angle.

and you wrote code twice so in one frame it gets even bigger. I share the code which I updated maybe it will be more clear to see the changes in it.

```
float rY = 0.1; 
float rX = 0.1;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P3D);
}

void draw() { 

  background(3);
  lights();

  fill(125, 175, 225,175);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2); // you do not need to write translate twice

  //box
  rY += 0.01; // you need only once to add the rotation value per frame
  rotateY(-rY); // negative rotation for the difference from sphere
  rX += 0.01;
  rotateX(-rX);
  noStroke();
  box(50); 

  //sphere
  rotateY(rY); 
  rotateX(rX);
  noFill();
  stroke(125, 175, 225,125);
  sphere(125);

  popMatrix();

  println(rY);
}
```